# Special characters(Registered trademark, TM- trademark, smiley etc.) are not displayed correctly on the UI

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsp-tags

I am developing a webpage(.jsp) where I m fetching data in the form of JSON object and then parsing it so as to display it on the UI, where the display is not correct.e.g.,BlackBerry�
etc. I have written all the business logic in JAVA code. When I have checked the response in JAVA, it was correct.

To fix the issue, I put a work-around to change the particular characters to their HTML form(e.g., For Registered Trademark, I replaced it with HTMLcode and it worked.But, as the Data is very long, I don't think it is a good practice.

I have checked some answers, where I found the encodiong issue. But, when I checked the HTML file, it was already there as

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Could anyone provide help on this.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: code snippet will be good!

Comment: Can you hard code those special character in jsp and check it whether formatting correctly or not in UI

Comment: Forgot to update the thread, The issue was related to UTF-8 character encoding only.For fixing the same, I have encoded the response to UTF-8 at servlet side and the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

When building a JSON string, all strings within MUST be encoded in UTF-8. This is a *requirement* of JSON. It seems like you're failing to do this, and therefore the receiving end of the JSON cannot read that character (since characters in the 128-255 range are invalid unless encoded properly)

Check your encoding where the JSON is being written to fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks for this pointer.I got your point.Could you please tell me how to set the Encoding for a JSON string.When I checked the response, It was correct.Please provide your inputs on this.

Comment: That depends entirely on how you're building the string.